# Oracle SQLcl apex export "-split" option

Tags: version-control, oracle-apex, sqlcl

If your application page number has more than 5 digit then "-split" option produce not page_NNNNN.sql file, but page_NNNNN_XXX.sql where XXX just some `ORDER BY` suffix. Therefore, **the same page may be sliced to different result file** (comparing to previous run).

1. You have only pages 100001 and 100005. Result: page_10000_001.sql for page 100001, page_10000_002.sql for page 100005 (for example, I don't remeber exact file names);
2. You have added page 100002. Result: page_10000_001.sql for 100001, page_10000_002.sql for page 100002 and page_10000_003.sql for page 100005.

This "feature" ruins possibility of correct APEX-Git (and any other versioning system) binding. Is there a way for "-split" option to always save APEX page into .sql file with static name (based only on page number)?

Comment: What is the exact command you are running from SQLcl and what version? `-slice` does not appear to be a valid parameter.

Comment: Sorry, "-split"